# Unity integration with AWS

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, unity-game-engine, aws-sdk-net

'InvalidDataException' exists in both 'AWSSDK.Core, Version=3.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' and 'netstandard, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' - This is the error that appears when I import any package of AWS SDK into my unity project. Every steps in AWS SDK is followed correctly. Is there any suggestion to overcome this error? Or any other methods to make connection between AWS and unity? Feedbacks are welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used AWS, but have been using Firebase for years and have encountered that error several times.
A solution I think is to delete one of the two: either "AWSSDK.Core" or "netstandard".
Since they are both critical to you, try the alternative route: Does that message refer to some script where that property is called? Could you cast that line of code?
Also check if AWSSDK.Core is up to date.

**if you think my answer helped you, you can mark it as [accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) and vote positively. I would very much appreciate it :)**